# What is the SQL command to forcibly close all other connections to the a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the SQL command to forcibly close all other connections to the a database. 
This is for SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way using [ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx)

```
ALTER DATABASE foo SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

You can use KILL but you want to prevent re-connections too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Kill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) statement to close a single connection:

> Terminates a user process that is
>   based on the session ID (SPID in SQL
>   Server 2000 and earlier)

Without further comment, here's a stored procedure we've used off and on over the years, to close all connections, using `kill`.  I'm sure there's a better/non-cursor way to do this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE kill_database_users @arg_dbname sysname
AS

declare @a_spid smallint
declare @msg    varchar(255)
declare @a_dbid int

select
    @a_dbid = sdb.dbid
from    master..sysdatabases sdb
where   sdb.name = @arg_dbname

declare db_users insensitive cursor for
select
    sp.spid
from    master..sysprocesses sp
where   sp.dbid = @a_dbid

open db_users

fetch next from db_users into @a_spid
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
    select @msg = 'kill '+convert(char(5),@a_spid)
    print @msg
    execute (@msg)
    fetch next from db_users into @a_spid
    end

close db_users
deallocate db_users
```