# Killing ALL user connections to the database SQL 2005 with rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, kill, rollback

The issue is that there are certain users that keep certain applications open instead of shutting down their PCs overnight - this keeps locks on tables and that has an impact on  other systems that rely on the tables being in an 'unlocked' state to do their updates etc.

I want to kill all USER connections (only) to a database. I will need to run this as a job on a nightly basis. I don't want to use:

ALTER DATABASE xxx SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

As I do not want to destroy the integrity of the database transaction logging.

Any ideas as to how this may be accomplished?

Thanks in advance,

JR

Comment: "I do not want to destroy the integrity of the database transaction logging" - what are you talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the SQL command to forcibly close all other connections to the a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907598/what-is-the-sql-command-to-forcibly-close-all-other-connections-to-the-a-databas)

Comment: @"Damien_The_Unbeliever what are you talking about?" Whoops - I may have been thinking of 'simple' instead of 'single.